# Within 6 months - How many days is this?

Tags: phrase-meaning

If instructions state that "applicant must submit their application within 6 months from the date of purchase", what is this length of time?  For example, if the purchase is made January 15, is "within 6 months" June 15, or the end of June?  Essentially 180 vs 195 days.  Note that "month" is not specified as "calendar", "lunar", or "30-day period" (or defined in any manner within the instructions).

Comment: Is this about English Language?   Or arithmetic?

Comment: Related (on Law.SE): [The legal length of one month](http://law.stackexchange.com/questions/542/the-legal-length-of-one-month)

Comment: @Lawrence 's link is a good one

Comment: Where does 195 come from?

Comment: Here is a good source (Cornell University Law School affiliate site) that explains for many legal actions, when not specified more precisely, the expiration gets extended to the first business day after the month anniversary day .  It gets pretty specific about not counting the first  day etc... for those that are curious : https://www.law.cornell.edu/rules/frcp/rule_6 Computing Time. The following rules apply in computing any time period specified in these rules, in any local rule or court order, or in any statute that does not specify a method of computing time.

Comment: Note that there's a serious mistake in your question.  The month anniversaries of Jan 15 are (1) Feb 15, (2) Mar 15, (3) Apr 15, (4) May 15, (5) Jun 15, (6) Jul 15.  Jan 15 to **Jun 15** is 151 days (in a non-leap year), if I add correctly.  Jan 15 to **Jul 15** (ie, 6 months) is 181 days.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking for a legal interpretation, not about general usage in English.

Answer (score 2):

Given the statement *"applicant must submit their application within 6 months from the date of purchase"* with the purchase being on January 15, it would be easy and logical to argue that any date up to and including July 14 (not June) was within six months.  July 15 might cause problems of interpretation (does *within* include the edge?) and July 16 can easily be argued to be more than 6 months after January 15.

Law may be different in jurisdictions using different months, notably those associated with lunar months, which are typically shorter than those in the Gregorian calendar

Comment: Your answer is correct, including its discussion of the "fuzzy" issue of the last day.  I don't think that any administrative or legal jurisdiction (in the US) would argue differently.

Comment: Actually, for many computations whether the final day was a business day or not might extend the time period for days beyond the actual 6 month anniversary. https://www.law.cornell.edu/rules/frcp/rule_6 is an interesting read

Comment: @Hot Licks.  Yes, I apparently mis-calculated 5 vs 6 months in my question, but the math isn't my primary concern.  I tried to use that as an example to simplify my question and goofed it.  The question is really about  the use of "within" and the generic use of "month" and if that construct represented some sort of standard, usage, or interpretation that might pin down the meaning or if its just poorly constructed and arguably vague.  Personally, I'd prefer something like "no greater than 180 calendar days from date of purchase".

Answer (score -1):

Rule of thumb is it's calendar months.

Thus, six months from January 15 would be June 15; and from March 15 it would be August 15.

Comment: Then, what will be the date if we say within one month from January 15?

Comment: June is the 6th month.  January is the 1st.  That's 5 months between, not 6.

Comment: Ie, **your answer is wrong, just like the question.**